# Int pointer type to int

Tags: c, visual-studio, types, casting, warnings

I'm having hard time working around one warning issued by VS2013.
What I have is a piece of code used for passing text to int var:

```
#define WRITE(txt)  { foo->bar.func = func_xyz; foo->bar.xyz.var = (((uint64_t) (uintptr_t) (txt)) & 0xFFFFFFFFu); } //where var is uint32_t
```

Which causes the compiler to return

```
warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'uintptr_t' to 'uint32_t', possible loss of data.
```

Now unfortunately I can't possibly change var type to anything else than uint32_t and unfortunately I fall victim to preprocessor directive

```
#ifdef  _WIN64
    typedef unsigned __int64    uintptr_t;
```

Is there any way to get around this warning and do it the right way? I'm 100% sure that this is fully working (simply because it is), but any kind of warning is unacceptable.

Comment: What is txt when you apply the macro? The warning doesn't appear on the macro definition, I assume. What does the code look like where the warning is?

Comment: You are casting the value to `uint64_t` and assigning to a `uint32_t` what do you think the warning means?

Comment: nicomp - it's just passed, e.g WRITE("zyx");

Comment: Why "can't possibly change var type to anything else than uint32_t"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One more cast should do it:

```
#define WRITE(txt) {                                                             \
    foo->bar.func = func_xyz;                                                    \
    foo->bar.xyz.var = (uint32_t)(((uint64_t) (uintptr_t) (txt)) & 0xFFFFFFFFu); \
} //where var is uint32_t
```

Comment: The cast will get rid of the warning, but that doesn't make it *right*.

Comment: What you fail to see (maybe it's just the fact I never mentioned it) is that piece of "code" I provided is not exactly correct and just serves illustration. I am fully aware of all the boundaries you mentioned, and project it is used in has all the mechanisms allowing it to recognize any fault. 
And Iharobs answer solves it perfectly, thank you a lot.

Comment: If you say so, @Sven, but I find that doubtful.

Comment: @John Bollinger, he was pretty sure that it was fully working. Thus, the only thing left to me is removing the warning.

Comment: If code requires `foo->bar.xyz.var` to be undersized, then the conversion should embedded a range test with a fatal error when out of range.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to get around this warning and do it the right way?

If `txt` can be a pointer, and you intend to capture its value in a form from which the pointer can be recovered, then no, what you are doing is inherently wrong, and the compiler is warning you about a *bona fide* flaw in your code.

The type `uintptr_t` is an unsigned integer type wide enough to hold the value of any pointer converted to integer.  In win64, pointers can be wider than 32 bits, so `uintptr_t` must be wider, too.  (And you are not a "victim" of that -- that type is specified by the standard as having those characteristics.)  There is no voodoo that can make arbitrary 64-bit values fit in 32 bits.

> I'm 100% sure that this is fully working (simply because it is), but any kind of warning is unacceptable.

It may have worked in all your tests, on your particular test hardware, on your particular test scenarios, and maybe even in production.  That does not mean it is correct, or that it will work reliably on other hardware, or with other inputs.